# application crashes on calling popViewController : error: alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:

Tags: iphone, crash, alert

A description of the problem is as follows:

I have a view, say, view A. To enter certain data, I have an alert,with a text field inside it, which pops up. Once the user enters data into the text field, i have an alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: function as follows :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    [ amountEntered resignFirstResponder];           //dismiss keyboard

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {                          //OK clicked, do something

        if(lblShowTypedText.text)

            data.investmentAmount = lblShowTypedText.text ;

        [myTable reloadData];
    }
}
```

Then I have a submit button on my View A, which when clicked pops back to the previous view. Here is where my app crashes. There is no message in the console, however after many runs, I got one message like this:

*** -[NSCFType alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3c4dce0
2010-06-24 15:33:22.970 BankingAppln[2895:207] CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: *** -[NSCFType alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3c4dce0

Thus i have narrowed down the problem to the alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: function. If I do not call the alert, but directly pop back to the previous view, everything is fine.

I must be doing something wrong in my alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: function.

Pls help!!

Comment: If you run in debug mode it should stop right away at the crashing point and the stack trace will point you to the problem. Also, calling -viewWillAppear: is most probably a bug. It's not a method you call, ever. It's a method you override...

Comment: i call viewWillAppear, as i want the display in the main view to be updated as the user has entered it in the textfield..so my viewWillAppear contains a [myTable reloadData]..is there an alternative way of doing that without calling viewWillAppear?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I did away with viewWillAppear..i still get the app crash, with the same error as I posted above

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

- You set the delegate of the AlertView to the right class (View A)?
- Your class (View A) implements the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol.
- Probably not, but you never know: You're classname is not equal to a name in apple's private api (don't laugh, happened to me a week ago, costed me 2 hours to figure out)?

EDIT:
Another thing to check:

- Your delegate method has the right return type (I think it's "void" in that case)?

Comment: I checked all that you said, all of them are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have this method, alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:,  in your class?  and post the code when you call it as well

Comment: yes, the function is in my class.. also I never make a call to the method, does it not get invoked when appropriate buttons are clicked in the alert? sorry If I'm wrong, but im new to Iphone development. What I basically want to do, is when data is entered into the text field in the alert, and OK is clicked, I want to store this data, and display it in the view..

Comment: Once the user enters data into the text field, i have an alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: function as follows :

      (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

These lines make me confused, your function is not alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:, it is alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex. Can you really post the function alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex ? The function is called because your class is the UIAlertView Delegate

Comment: sorry for the mistake, I was messing around with both the methods. My method is didDismissWithButtonIndex only. I have included the UIAlertView Delegate in my class.As Eiko pointed out, i removed the call to viewWillAppear and my function looks as above.

Comment: Can you post the UIAlertView init code. Did you set the delegate to self? Can you try to copy the method name to the interface

Answer (score 0):

You need to post where you call the method..but from the error message you gave, the problem is you are calling your method incorrectly.

if it is a method you defined yourself with the implementation above use

```
[self alertView:myAlertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:myIndex];
```

also, in your declaration, you have a semicolon after the parameter `alertView` and you just need a space.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and it turns out that with Automatic Reference Counting in place, I needed to keep a reference to the popup around as a property so that it would not be reference collected. That much was fine but I got overzealous and started doing stuff like `popup = nil;` explicitly and that got me into trouble because some of the delegate methods for the popup were called after I had nil'ed out the reference that I was holding onto and now this popup was not around anymore and the framework crashed due to this little fact.

```
[__NSCFString alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9117c0
```

So I decided to simply keep allocating a new popup when it was needed and not explicitly nil'ing out the older references. This fixed the issue for me.